# GDAL local files VS ftp files

Tags: python, gdal

I can successfully get raster information when the raster file is located on my local file system:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
filename= "MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf"
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
print ( dataset.GetDriver().ShortName,dataset.GetDriver().LongName)
```

Output:

```
('HDF4', 'Hierarchical Data Format Release 4')
```

But, when I try this with the same raster file, which this time is located on a ftp server, I get an error:

```
import gdal   
from gdalconst import *
filename="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf"
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
print ( dataset.GetDriver().ShortName,dataset.GetDriver().LongName)
```

Output with error:

```
ERROR 4: `/vsimem/http_1/MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf' not recognised as a supported file format.

('HDF4', 'Hierarchical Data Format Release 4')
```

Why is this?

Comment: Why don't you download the files and process locally? will remove any potential networking issues.

Comment: @Mapperz At first I wanted to save them in PostGIS, but I did not find good documentation on how to do it. Then, I decided about a local file system, but when I realized GDAL provides ftp capabilities, I thought this would be the most straightforward way.<
Would you go for the PostGIS option?

Comment: local system to postgis (from 2.0.1) raster2pgsql via gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf4.html

Comment: @Mapperz I am not sure if I understood it correctly:
You are saying to first download rasters from ftp to file system, and then from file system store them to PostGIS using raster2pgsql? I assume it is not possible to store them directly from ftp to postgis.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`/vsicurl/`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsicurl) virtual filesystem syntax. From the [documentation](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html):

> Most GDAL raster and vector drivers use a GDAL-specific abstraction to
> access files. This makes it possible to access less standard types of
> files, such as in-memory files, compressed files (.zip, .gz, .tar,
> .tar.gz archives), encrypted files, files stored on network (either
> publicly accessible, or in private buckets of commercial cloud storage
> services), etc.
>
> Each special file system has a prefix, and the general syntax to name a file is `/vsiPREFIX/`...

And:

> `/vsicurl/` (http/https/ftp files: random access)
>
> `/vsicurl/` is a filesystem handler that allows on-the-fly random reading of files available through HTTP/FTP web protocols, without prior download of the entire file. It requires GDAL to be built against libcurl.
>
> Recognized filenames are of the form
> `/vsicurl/http[s]://path/to/remote/resource` or `/vsicurl/ftp://path/to/remote/resource`, where path/to/remote/resource is the URL of a remote resource.

For example:

```
filename="/vsicurl/ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf"
```